# Can we use closure in python for nested function? But it is giving me NameError: name 'add' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

```
def outerFunction(func): 
    def add(x,y):
        print(x+y)

    def sub(x,y):
        print(x-y)

    return func

calc_add=outerFunction(add)
calc_sub=outerFunction(sub)
calc_add(56,60)
calc_sub(56,7)
```

Comment: Do not use `add` or `sub` as a function name because it already exists in Python [Python Standard operators as functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html). Why don't you just call your functions in `outerfFunction` where they're declared outside ?

Comment: Yes you can, but still you need names defined before using them.

Comment: Yes I have tried and it worked but I am asking that can't I use it like the closure here making the nested function usable outside the outer function. And I have also tried with the different name other than (add or sub) but it is giving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to simulate a dynamic closure?

Try below:

```
def outerFunction(func):
    def add(x, y):
        print(x + y)

    def sub(x, y):
        print(x - y)

    return eval(func) # change string to real function

calc_add = outerFunction('add')
calc_sub = outerFunction('sub')
calc_add(56, 60)
calc_sub(56, 7)
```